# CSS3 lock prespective

Tags: html, css

In CSS transform is it possible to lock in the `example: perspective`. The issue I'm facing is on page zoom-in, the perspective changes on the browser.Ideally i need to keep the perspective locked-in.Zooming in and out moves the object perspective and then effects the shapes location inside the div.

[image]

```css
.a-div {
    width: 45%;
    height: 52%;
    top: 22%;
    left: 28%;
    position: fixed;  
    background-color:red;
    transform:rotateX(57deg)rotateY(2deg)rotateZ(38deg)skewx(0deg)skewy(0deg);
  
    /*  I need to add perspective to taper the top of the shape slightly., adding perspective makes the shape loose it positions co-ordinates on browser zooming. */
    }
```

```html
<div class="a-div">
  Example
</div>
```

The top point i need to come down a bit without effecting the other 3 corners in the snippet provided.

Comment: Can you post example code?

Comment: @AMACB updated question..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a `%` in your css rules. When you use `%`, the browser calculates the size based on the **width and height** of the window. So when you zoom in, the width and height decrease, but the `.a-div` takes up the same **percentage** of the window no matter what size.

Comment: Exactly that is the result i want But the issue is with perspective to prevent it from changing in some manner either a hack or something i am not aware of

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean by "a hack or something I am not aware of"?

Comment: perspective(1200); adding this to the class completely changes the dynamics of the div... now check the link

Answer (score 0):

The work around for me was to have the perspective set to 50,000. By doing this the browser zoom seem to make no difference giving me the result that i desired.

And for the container div i added `transform : perspective(500px)rotateX(0.001deg);`

The result allowed an image with an overlay that was inlined always over the image bg with depth.Full responsive with out media queries or js.